# Regular expression for valid function name ([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w]

Tags: c#, regex

I m using following reg exp for validating the name of function

```
([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w]
```

ex **addNumber** is a valid function , while now for changed requirements
user can also write **local:addNumber** .

I want to modify this regular expression in such a way so that it can allow single occurence of **local:**.

I tried but can't make a perfect one.

Comment: What actual language and environment are you using ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't using **(local:)?([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w]** fix your problem?

Edit: 
The regex in C# is actually **(local\:)?([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w]**, because :(colon) is a special character that has to be escaped. Thank you Russ C

Comment: what about (local\:)?([a-zA-Z]\w+)[^\w]

Comment: As i am not a C# developer I didn't know that colon is a special character. But if it is one, then simply escape it as Russ C specified.

Comment: What if it is "global:addNumber"? I think 'local' is just an example :)

Comment: @BeingSimplest no local is not just ex i want to specifically allow only local:    :)

Comment: To treat a discrete number of "modifiers" (local/global/custom) use ** | ** (or), like this: ((local|global|custom)\:)?([a-zA-Z]+)